# Recover myetherwallet account with json but without password

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, recovery

I have lost my usb stick which contained password for access to my myetherwallet.
Are there any ways to recover that, only thing I have is .json file, can I get from it private key or is there any way to recover password?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have any sort of idea what your password might be, you could try [the wallet recovery service by Dave](https://walletrecoveryservices.com/). [He has great reviews.](https://walletrecoveryservices.com/testimonials/)

Otherwise, there's not much you can do to recover your wallet. The keystore file is encrypted with your password, so you cannot get the private key without it.